# Cannot convert from sytem.activities.InArgument<System.Security.SecureString> to String for ToPlainString Variable while converting it into string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a `SecureString` to `String` and am encountered errors. Please help me! Thanks!

> Cannot convert from `sytem.activities.InArgument<System.Security.SecureString>` to `String` for ToPlainString Variable while converting it into string

```
namespace SecureStringToString {
    public static class Extensions {
        [Category("Input")]
        [RequiredArgument]
        public static InArgument<SecureString> ToPlainString { get; set; }

        [Category("Output")]
        public static OutArgument<string> Output { get; set; }
        static void main() {
            String Str = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(string.Empty, ToPlainString).Password;    //<- Cannot convert secure string to string

            output.set(Str);
           //<- output variable does not exist in in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for [NetworkCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) expects a `string` and a `SecureString`. You are passing it a `string` and a `InArgument<SecureString>`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm very new to this, can you please explain me in detail? and correct the code?